# start and enable docker for system using runit

Tags: docker, runit

I don't have systemd in my Linux but runit.

for systemd user, start and enable docker can be done as follows

```
 systemctl start docker.service
 
 systemctl enable docker.service
```

But how to start docker for runit users?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look maybe here:
https://docs.voidlinux.org/config/services/index.html

sections: `Basic Usage` & `Enabling Services`

Comment: Hey @J-Mous welcome to the site. Thanks a lot for your post.